# How to reliably transform ISO-8859 encoded characters into HTML entities with NodeJS?

Tags: html, node.js, encoding, character-encoding, iso

[The Expedia Hotel Database](http://developer.ean.com/database) is providing some of its data using the ISO-8859 encoding:

> 2. Files with ONLY English content are ISO-8859.

[However:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859)

> ISO/IEC 8859 is a joint ISO and IEC **series** of standards for 8-bit character encodings. The series of standards consists of numbered parts, such as ISO/IEC 8859-1, ISO/IEC 8859-2, etc. There are **15 parts**, excluding the abandoned ISO/IEC 8859-12. The ISO working group maintaining this series of standards has been disbanded.

So it a series of different encodings with notable differences, rather than a single one. My problem:

*How can I convert their "ONLY English content" data using NodeJS into a safer form to store in my database, that I can reliably deliver to user's browser, without worrying that the data get corrupted at the user end?*

I am thinking of trying to convert all data from ISO/IEC 8859-X (for each X = 1,...,16) into HTML entities first, and then check for presence of non-ASCII characters, which means the encoding was not correct and I have to take the next X. If none of the X works, that means this data entry is corrupted and should be discarded I suppose, as it will be unlikely displayed correctly. The whole task feel somewhat cumbersome, so I am wondering if there are simpler ways.

Note that even though the content is declared "ONLY English content", many data entries do actually contain accented characters that might get corrupted in a wrong encoding.

Comment: English text does use accented characters and diacritics and ligatures. It is unfortunate that they have ineptly communicated the encoding of the "ONLY English" data. You could just take their UTF-16 data.

Comment: @TomBlodget Their `UTF-16` files are different. They are used for multi-language content.